# How to build executable and shared libraries in same cmake project on windows/msvs

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cmake, shared-libraries

what I want to do is :

- create a shared library and export its API to be usable by other programs
- create a simple executable in the same project that uses the library (to show concrete example of how to use the library for example
- build it using cmake, must work with Visual Studio (2010) and windows 7

I tried this code (quick test case) :

CMakeLists.txt

```
PROJECT (minimalcpp)
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED (VERSION 2.6)

SET(LIBSAMPLE_HEADERS func_simple.h)
SET(LIBSAMPLE_SRCS func_simple.cpp)

ADD_LIBRARY (minimalcpp SHARED ${LIBSAMPLE_SRCS})

ADD_EXECUTABLE (test-pure-cpp test-pure-cpp.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES (test-pure-cpp minimalcpp)

# THIS WORKS BUT IT IS NOT WHAT I WANT :
# ADD_EXECUTABLE (test-pure-cpp test-pure-cpp.cpp ${LIBSAMPLE_SRCS})
```

macros.h

```
#ifndef MACROS_H
#define MACROS_H

#if defined _WIN32 || defined __CYGWIN__
    #if minimalcpp_EXPORTS
        #define MINIMALCPP_API __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define MINIMALCPP_API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
#endif

#endif
```

func_simple.h

```
#ifndef LIB_SAMPLE_FUNC_SIMPLE_H
#define LIB_SAMPLE_FUNC_SIMPLE_H

#include "macros.h"

namespace sample {
MINIMALCPP_API void f1(int nmax);
}

#endif // LIB_SAMPLE_FUNC_SIMPLE_H
```

func_simple.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "func_simple.h"

void sample::f1(int nmax) {
  int i ;
  for(i=0 ; i < nmax ; i++) {
    std::cout << i << " -> " << i*i << std::endl;
  }
}
```

test-pure-cpp.cpp

```
#include "func_simple.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    sample::f1(5);
    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles but crashes directly at execution.

Error message :

```
Le programme s'est terminé subitement.
... a quitté avec le code -1073741515
```

I am a beginner in C++ on windows, what did I do wrong ?
Thank you very much

Comment: Did you try compiling and running with a static library first, and did it work then? May be you're stating a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Another problem could be that windows doesn't find your DLL, you'll need to specify it's directory in the `PATH` variable then.

Comment: The code you have posted is fine and works as expected on my machine with VS2010. Could the problem be in your `test-pure-cpp.cpp`?

Comment: I added test-pure-cpp source code in example. It works if I compile it as static library (and after removal of __declspec(...))

Comment: The good answer was that windows doesn't find your DLL !!! Thank you very much. I can't imagine having lost such time on a such simple problem ... and I can't imagine having a message like this for this kind of problem (maybe I am too much used to linux/gcc that raises a more explicit message to me)

Answer (score 0):

see [g-makulik] answer :

In this case, this message means that dll is not found and that is why application crashes.
One solution is to say to cmake to put dll and executable in same directory, in bin for example :

```
SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
SET(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
SET(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
```

This convention is used in libraries like Qt for example.